# Firebase 'setValue' Function Repeats And Does Not Stop Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I Am Sending Integers To My Database, And Should Be Called **Once**, But Is Being Updated 100's Of Times. The Database Gets Filled Up Quickly, As If There Is An Infinite Loop.

How Can I Call The `setValue` Function To Upload An Integer Without It Repeating In A Loop? Is There A Different Way To Do It?

```
let newNumber = self.OldPoints + 20;
print("\(String(newNumber))")
self.databaseRefer.child("Users").child(Name).child("PointsAndConesInfo").child("CurrentPoints").childByAutoId().setValue(newNumber)
```

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information for anyone to help you.  There's no loop here, and even `databaseRefer` isn't defined.  Please see [how to create a minimum, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Make sure to include (minimal) example data from your database, in JSON form if at all possible (you can export it from the console).

Comment: I imagine this is within a handler for observing changes in a node value, rather than observing once. So you are setting the value within the observe handler, which will call the observe handler again, which will set the value again, which will call the observe handler again, and so on perpetually. You want to use `DatabaseReference.observeSingleEvent`, not `DatabaseReference.observe`.

Comment: Why have you capitalised every word?

Comment: I think @DavidChopin has a spot on answer. However, there's not enough code in your question to duplicate the issue. e.g. when/where is that code being called from? Do you have an observer on any of the referenced nodes in your question? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely using `DatabaseReference.observe` and then updating the value within its completion handler. `DatabaseReference.observe` will be called **every time** the value in question updates. So if you are observing changes, then updating the value of the same reference, it will loop infinitely.

If you want to observe the value **once** and then update the same value in the completion handler, use `DatabaseReference.observeSingleEvent` instead. This will prevent the completion handler from being called a second, third, fourth, up to infinity times.